# Pyccuracy hangs in Ubuntu Karmic

Tags: bdd, ubuntu-9.10

I was able to successfully run suites of tests before upgrading to
Karmic.  Now when running pyccuracy_console, Pyccuracy starts, outputs
"Running first test...", and hangs.

Is anyone aware of a fix for this?

- OS: Ubuntu 9.1 Karmic
- Pyccuracy: v1.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyccuracy relies on Selenium Server to do its testing. Upgrading from **Selenium 1.0 beta** to **1.0.1** fixed the issue.

http://seleniumhq.org/download/